# Custom delegate classes

Tags: ios, delegates, uiimagepickercontroller

Again working with existing code. ViewFinderManager is delegate class. The screen is being presented modally. But I'm not able to use the cancel and done button on nav bar.

```
AlbumPickerViewController *apVC = [[AlbumPickerViewController alloc] init];
OMWUINavigationController *navC = [[OMWUINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:apVC];
[self presentModalViewController:navC animated:YES];
[[ViewFinderManager sharedInstance] addListener:self];
```

Button in AlbumPickerViewController:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [UIBarButtonItem buttonSquareEdgeButtonWithTitle:@"done" color:[UIColor blueColor] target:self action:@selector(doneHandler)];
```

doneHandler:

```
- (void)doneHandler {
   [[ViewFinderManager sharedInstance] endPicking];
}
```

How to make done button work. There is a cancel button on same lines too.
Also is it correct to add self as listener ?

Please let me know if I'm missing some piece of information here.

Comment: Have you put in a breakpoint or an NSLog to see if doneHandler is being called?

Comment: Yes, it is being called.

Comment: Ok well if its being called what is [[ViewFinderManager sharedInstance] endPicking]; suppose to do?